# How to design a multiplier using only multiplexer?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, binary

I am asked to make a multipier that takes a three bits input $$x=(x_1, x_2,x_3)$$ and a control signal \$s\$ so that the results will be a hexadecimal 4 bit number $$z=(z_3,z_2,z_1,z_0)$$ such that \$z = x\$  when \$s=0\$ and \$z=2x\$ when \$s=1\$

basically i need to multiply \$x\$ by \$2\$ whenever \$s\$ is high

Comment: It's a *number*; "hexadecimal" is the system that you use to *write* that number. In your question's context, that isn't even the notation you use (which is binary, not hexadecimal).

Answer (score 4):

When \$s\$ is 0 then the result is \$z = (z_3, z_2, z_1, z_0) = (0, x_2 ,x_1, x_0)\$ and when \$s\$ is 1 then the result is \$z = (z_3, z_2, z_1, z_0) = (x_2 ,x_1, x_0, 0)\$.

So the operation you are basically doing is just shifting input by \$s\$ bits (i.e \$z = x << s\$). This is because a multiplication by 2 is equal to a 1 bit shift.